# Custom R lm function within the tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, lme4

I have a simple question about creating custom lm functions within the `tidyverse` framework.

I basically want a function that runs a custom model with me with one free variable.

```
model <- function(x){
  lmer(paste("cyl ~", x, "+ (1|disp)"), data = .)
}
```

And then I want to use this in `dplyr`'s `do`

```
mtcars %>% 
  do(x = model("hp"))
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass data to the function :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

model <- function(data, x){
  lmer(paste("cyl ~", x, "+", "(1|disp)"), data = data)
}
```

and then call it like :

```
mtcars %>% model('hp')

#Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#Formula: cyl ~ hp + (1 | disp)
#   Data: data
#REML criterion at convergence: 96.2
#Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
# disp     (Intercept) 0.927   
# Residual             0.441   
#Number of obs: 32, groups:  disp, 27
#Fixed Effects:
#(Intercept)           hp  
#     3.1866       0.0196
```

Or

```
mtcars %>% summarise(mod = list(model(., 'hp')))

#                                                  mod
#1 <S4 class ‘lmerMod’ [package “lme4”] with 13 slots>
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the summarise approach: `Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  first argument must be atomic`

Comment: Are you sure you are using my function and not yours? Because it works for me without any error as shown.

Comment: Yes, and I'm on R 3.5.3; `dplyr` 0.8.5; and `lmer` 3.1-2

Comment: Did you try restarting your R session and trying this? and BTW I am on R 4.0.0 now which was released couple of days back. You might want to try upgrading.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using `do` instead of `summarise`

Comment: Glad you got it worked however note that `do` may or may not be around in the future.